# Weird effect when applying transparent border over an element with a gradient background

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

When applying a transparent border over an element with a `linear-gradient` as the background, I get a weird effect.

[image]

Notice the left and right sides of the element don't have the proper colours (they're some way switched) and are weirdly *flat*.

**HTML**

```
<div class="colors">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.colors {
    width: 100px;
    border: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    height: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, 
        #78C5D6,
        #459BA8,
        #79C267,
        #C5D647,
        #F5D63D,
        #F08B33,
        #E868A2,
        #BE61A5);
}
```

*Why* is this showing a weird effect on the left and right side of the element, and *What* can I do about it?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fzndodgx/3/

Comment: Isn't this just because borders are separate from the content box? i.e. the background.

Comment: A solution would be to have a second div using ::after: http://jsfiddle.net/a1h2yh11/

Answer (score 54, accepted):

That's because the starting and ending points of the `gradient` are at the edges of the `padding-box` and `border` is rendered outside the `padding-box`. So, the borders look funny because the `background` is repeated on each side outside the `padding-box` to cover the `border-box`.

The `box-shadow:inset` is rendered inside the `padding-box` (just like background) and gives visually the same effect as a `border`, so you could try using that in place of `border`:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
padding: 10px;
```

Because a `box-shadow` doesn't take up any space, you need to increase your padding accordingly.

Illustration of `padding-box` and `border-box`:
[image]

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/fzndodgx/5/

Comment: why does setting `box-sizing: border-box` not fix the OP's original code?

Comment: This worked like a charm, but I didn't find the explanation very clear. The fact that the starting and ending points of the gradient are at the edges of the `padding-box` still doesn't explain why the left border has the ending point, and the right border the starting point (if I understood correctly)

Comment: Backgrounds repeat - so it is extending beyond the bounds of the padding-box and then starting again - hence the apparent reversal.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow `box-sizing` affects how the `size` of the element is measured, not how the `background` is rendered.

Comment: I don't think it was good on your part to add what had already been covered in another answer into your own a long time after the other one was posted. At the very least you could have mentioned about the other answer in your edit.

Comment: downvoted.. because of copy pasting answer from other post. don't try to take credit of others work.

Comment: Uh, calling it a copy-paste is a bit of a stretch, and it's not like this user *replaced* his original answer with the new one. In any case, Harry's answer still offers an explanation of his solution so it remains superior to this one.

Comment: Sorry, hadn't bothered to read his long answer before making an edit and didn't realize that solution was already proposed. I can remove my edited bit though, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @IlpoOksanen: That's ok mate. No worries :)

Answer (score 51):

### Solution

The simplest way to fix this issue would be by setting the value for the `background-origin` property as `border-box` .

```css
.colors {
  width: 100px;
  border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #78C5D6, #459BA8, #79C267, #C5D647, #F5D63D, #F08B33, #E868A2, #BE61A5);
  background-origin: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors"></div>
```

---

### Reason for the behavior mentioned in question

The following are the relevant `background` properties that determine the way the background gradient is displayed for this case:

- [`background-origin`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds-3/#background-origin) - The default value is `padding-box`. It means that the background is actually positioned with respect to the padding box and so starts from after the `border`.
- [`background-repeat`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds-3/#background-repeat) - The default value for this is `repeat`. It means that the image should be repeated as much as needed to cover the entire background painting area.
- [`background-clip`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds-3/#background-clip) - The default value for this is `border-box`. It means that the image should be present under the area occupied by the borders of the box also.

Now combining all three we can see that the border must be repeated as much as possible for it to be present even under the borders and that it's starting position is after the border of the box. This implies that the background must be repeated in a cyclic manner so as to fill up the area under the border on the left side. Because of this the left border has the color as the right end of the gradient and vice-versa.

By changing it to `border-box`, we are making the background get positioned with respect to the border box.  This setting **also has an effect on the size of the background image** and the reason for it is described below in detail.

---

### Why does `box-sizing: border-box` not work?

Setting `box-sizing` as `border-box` does not bring about any change because that property affects only the size of the box. It has absolutely no effect on the following:

- The size of the gradient image (actual calculation logic is described below)
- The starting point (or position) of the gradient image
- The repetition of the background image

---

### How is the size of the gradient calculated?

As per [**W3C spec**](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds-3/#background-size), the below is how the image's dimensions are calculated when no explicit size is provided (default value is `auto`).

> If the **image** has neither an intrinsic width nor an intrinsic height, its size is determined as for ‘contain’

Note how it talks about the size of the image and not that of the box. In essence, irrespective of the size of the box, the size of the background image would be calculated based on the definition for keyword `contain` when the image itself has no intrinsic height ([which CSS gradients don't have unlike images](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#intrinsic-dimensions)).

The **definition for `contain`** is as follows:

> Scale the image, while preserving its intrinsic aspect ratio (if any), to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the **background positioning area**.

**Background positioning area** is defined as follows (under `background-origin` property definition):

> For elements rendered as a single box, specifies the background positioning area

Thus, when the image has no intrinsic height (and in this case no `background-size` also), the size of the image would be equal to that of `background-origin`'s value (which in our case is `padding-box`).

This is why even setting the `box-sizing` as `border-box` has no effect.

<sup>**Note:** emphasis within the quoted texts are all mine</sup>

---

If you explicitly set the `background-size` as the size of the box, you would notice how the issue is resolved on the right side but not on the left side. This is because now the image is large enough to not repeat under the right border but its starting point is still after the left border.

```css
.colors {
  width: 100px;
  border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #78C5D6, #459BA8, #79C267, #C5D647, #F5D63D, #F08B33, #E868A2, #BE61A5);
  background-size: 110px 60px;
}
.colors-2 {
  width: 100px;
  border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #78C5D6, #459BA8, #79C267, #C5D647, #F5D63D, #F08B33, #E868A2, #BE61A5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-size: 100px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors">
</div>
<div class="colors-2">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice explanation for possible different workarounds.

Comment: @afonsomatos: The approach covered in this answer is not a workaround. It is actually the proper solution to your problem :)

Answer (score 13):

The background is repeating itself under the border. The background runs only in the "body" of the element, under the border is an expansion and repeat starts occurring.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/9pcuj8bw/1/) example with `no-repeat` on the border.

**UPDATE**

Playing with background `position` & `size` can help by expanding the background and then adjusting it's location.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/9pcuj8bw/3/) out.

Or see snippet:

```css
.colors {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #78C5D6, #459BA8, #79C267, #C5D647, #F5D63D, #F08B33, #E868A2, #BE61A5);
  background-size: 117%;
  background-position-x: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Other answers have already shown how to fix the issue, but I thought I should just point out that if you increase the `border-width` it becomes apparent that the background is actually repeating.

```
.colors {
    width: 100px;
    border: 100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    height: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, 
        #78C5D6,
        #459BA8,
        #79C267,
        #C5D647,
        #F5D63D,
        #F08B33,
        #E868A2,
        #BE61A5);
}
```

will produce

[image]

Comment: @mflodin + 1 it does become more evident

Answer (score 4):

The gradient starts within the padding box according to the default CSS box model behaviour, so it makes sense that the very start and very end colours appear until infinity either side of the gradient, where the border would be.

The same is true of this gradient (NSFW):

[image: A GOD AWFUL EYE SORE]

It continues infinitely in the starting value (violet) to the left, and continues infinitely with the end value (orange) to the right. It can continue infinitely upwards with this gradient, and so it does.

That's my understanding of why this is appearing so, a solution would to use a different box model.

Comment: ... why did you tag the gradient as not safe for work?

Comment: because it's super ugly >.>

Comment: My boss caught me looking at this gradient and now I have to meet with HR. Thanks a lot Aaron.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Stackoverflow looks sufficiently business like and serious to browse casually (unless you have activated tag based thread highlighting). If asked directly you can always say: "I am here to find the solution to problem X". Big, colorful images ruin that impression.

Answer (score 4):

The default value of [`background-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin) property is `padding-box` which means the background is positioned and sized relative to the padding box.

The background also *extends* below border since the [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) property defaults to `border-box`; it simply repeats itself below the border. This is why you see the right side of background below left border and vice versa.

So, just change the origin:

```css
.colors {
  width: 100px;
  border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #78C5D6, #459BA8, #79C267, #C5D647, #F5D63D, #F08B33, #E868A2, #BE61A5);
  background-origin: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors"></div>
```

Alternately you can play with background size and position: add 20px to the background size and position it at -10px -10px:

```css
.colors {
  width: 100px;
  border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #78C5D6, #459BA8, #79C267, #C5D647, #F5D63D, #F08B33, #E868A2, #BE61A5);
  background-position: -10px -10px;
  background-size: calc(100% + 20px) calc(100% + 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="colors"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `box-shadow`, you could use `border-image` and adjust the colors of the gradient: http://jsfiddle.net/9pcuj8bw/5/

```css
.colors {
    width:100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, 
        #78C5D6,
        #459BA8,
        #79C267,
        #C5D647,
        #F5D63D,
        #F08B33,
        #E868A2,
        #BE61A5) no-repeat;
    border: 10px solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, 
        #0bc3b8,
        #068e8c,
        #f8c617,
        #ea5f24,
        #b2492c) 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors"></div>
```

**Careful** this works not on IE10 or lower: http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image

Comment: You mean, "this doesn't work on IE10−" - it works on all other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, etc).

Comment: This is not the best solution and it doesn't achieve the wanted effect.