# Table with gradient borders and cell gradient borders

Tags: html, css, border, linear-gradients

I'd like to achieve a table with gradient on the border and div borders acting as is they were a whole item, by that I mean that the border color of the cells should be diferent.

[image: Table with gradients]

That's what I've got so far:

```css
table tr:first-child td {
  border-top: 0;
}
table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
table tr td:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
}
table tr td:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
td {
  border-right: 2px solid #bebebe;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #bebebe;
}
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table {
  /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 20px;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee 0%, #bebebe 100%);
  border-image-slice: 20;
  border-image-repeat: stretch;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px black;
}
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<table class="tablagradiente" align="center" width="41%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Sesiones Ordinarias</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Sesiones Extraordinarias</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Primera Sesión Extraordinaria 2015</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Solution

You can actually achieve what you want without `border-image` property just by setting the following:

```
table {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 0%, blue 100%); /* the gradient */
  background-origin: border-box; /* set background to start from border-box */
  border-spacing: 5px; /* space between each cell */
  border: 5px solid transparent; /* optional */
}
```

**Browser Support:**

- [Background Image](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts) property also has much better browser support than [Border Image](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image).

---

### Explanation

In essence what we are doing here is the following:

- Add the `linear-gradient` as the `background` of the table.
- Set the origin of the background such that it starts from the `border-box` of the table. (For more details on `background-origin`, please refer [**my answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115024/weird-gradient-border-effect/31120774#31120774)).
- Separate the border between the table cells & rows (**default** setting) such that the `background` of the `table` is visible through the space in between.
- Add an extra transparent `border` to your table itself. This is optional and is only required because the table border in your image seems thicker than the border between the cells.

```css
table {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 0%, blue 100%);  /* the gradient */
  background-origin: border-box;  /* set background to start from border-box */
  border-spacing: 5px;  /* space between each cell */
  border: 5px solid transparent;  /* optional */
}
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* Just for demo */

table {
  width: 500px;
}
td {
  background: white; /* if not set cell would also be transparent and show the gradient */
}
```

```html
<!-- prefix free lib for older browsers -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<table class="tablagradiente" align="center" width="41%">
  <tr>
    <td><p>Sesiones Ordinarias</p></td>
    <td><p>Sesiones Extraordinarias</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    <td><p>Primera Sesión Extraordinaria 2015</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    <td><p>Primera Sesión Extraordinaria 2015</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    <td><p>Primera Sesión Extraordinaria 2015</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

<sup>**Note:** I have used a red to blue gradient in the answer to make the effect more apparent to the eye.</sup>

[image]