# Multiple background images, gradient and image, matching scale of image

Tags: html, image, css, radial-gradients

I have a background made up of an image and a gradient.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWrKGv

I'm using the following CSS:

```
.row {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 150px;
  min-height: 750px;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient( 50% 50%, circle farthest-side, rgb(201, 2, 10) 0%, rgb(0, 0, 0) 100%), url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11795964/deer-antlers.jpg");
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

When you resize the page, the image begins to scale while the gradient stays the same size. I would like them to scale at the same time, so that you do not see the image being cut.

[image: gradient not scaling]

Comment: You should consider creating a "gradiented" image, so that you don't need the CSS gradient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gradient doesn't scale because the dimensions of the container element determines the size of the gradient. So, irrespective of whether  page is resized or not, the element (and in turn, the gradient) are 750px tall. (Note that you have two `min-height` settings and so the latter would override  former). You can find more info about the calculation of size for gradient images [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115024/weird-gradient-border-effect/31120774#31120774).

Now coming to the case with the image, even though you have set the `background-size` as `contain` (which is also the default size for gradients), images have an intrinsic aspect ratio and hence they are automatically scaled in such a way that its height and width can fit inside the background positioning area while **preserving** its aspect ratio. So, as the width of the element changes (which happens due to the 50% width setting on the container) the height of the image also changes to preserve the ratio.

So, in short, your current settings will not achieve what you wish to, because (a) the gradient will not scale in height as it has no intrinsic aspect ratio (and there is no way to set one as far as I am aware) and (b) the image will scale.

Making the image scale without maintaining the aspect ratio may not be a desirable case and scaling gradients in the same way is not possible even if it is assigned a `background-size` (because then it won't scale and gets rendered as fixed size with/without repeat).

In my opinion the best fix is to assign the container's dimensions such that it is **always** proportionate to the dimensions of the image that it is going to hold. For example, in the below snippet, I have used an image which is 500px wide x 750px tall and so I have assigned the height and width of  container as `100vh` and `150vh` respectively. This would mean that when the height of the the viewport changes, both  height and width of the container will change. This would in-turn mean that even when the image is scaled its aspect ratio matches with the container and so will occupy the full available space.

```css
.row {
  display: block;
  width: 100vh;
  min-height: 150vh;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle farthest-side, rgb(201, 2, 10) 0%, rgb(0, 0, 0) 100%), url("http://lorempixel.com/500/750/nature/1");
  background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at 50% 50%, rgb(201, 2, 10) 0%, rgb(0, 0, 0) 100%), url("http://lorempixel.com/500/750/nature/1");
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you resize the screen the image won't fit exactly for the height and width you indicated. As you've set bg size to contain row will be bigger then the image and the gradient will use all row space. This is an alternative:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .row{
   height:225px;
  }
}
```

Dont forget to add on stuff for head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```