# Single line (shorthand) background style?

Tags: css, background, background-image

I'm following this guide: [CSS background Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp).

```css
background: color image position/size repeat origin clip attachment initial|inherit;
```

I have this background CSS:

```css
background-color: grey;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
background-origin: content-box;
```

I'm trying to convert it to one line:

```css
background: grey center / contain no-repeat content-box;
```

I need the background image and grey to be the background of the padding too.

Where am I going wrong?

```css
div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    background: grey center / contain no-repeat content-box;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/50/NES_Super_Mario_Bros.png)"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asgs4zdh/)

Comment: background-image is missing

Comment: Apart from missing image, I notice nothing else wrong.

Comment: background image is specified on the div itself, sorry forgot to mention

Comment: How and where is the `background-image` set on the `div`? Have you checked the possibility of the shorthand setting overwriting it?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that declaration other than the assumption that the image is declared elsewhere. What problem are you facing?

Comment: The issue I am facing is that it does not take into account origin content box

Comment: @panthro: You may have forgotten to actually specify this in your question.

Comment: start by using a [reputable information source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background#Formal_syntax). Doesn't look like your code is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I forgot, so any ideas?

Comment: I've tried the same piece of code on a div which has padding and the content-box setting seems to work fine. Maybe you should create a demo.

Comment: I'll create a fiddle.

Comment: I have created a fiddle

Comment: @panthro: Looks like you maybe have an understanding problem too. Padding is not part of `content-box`. If you need padding to have background then it should be `padding-box` (or `border-box` because `padding-box` didn't work in some earlier versions of Chrome). I've voted to reopen the question.

Comment: This is a problem with the shorthand. If you just set one <box> value in the end (in this case 'content-box'), it will set background-origin AND background-clip to that value.
Therefor you have to set your background-clip after that. Final code then looks like this:
`background: grey center / contain no-repeat content-box border-box;`
See [W3C background spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background) on that.

Answer (score 3):

> I need the background image and grey to be the background of the padding too.

If you need the `background-image` **and** grey to be the background of the padding too then you should set `background-clip`  as `padding-box` instead of `content-box`. `content-box` area does not include the padding or the border areas.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background: grey center / contain no-repeat padding-box;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/50/NES_Super_Mario_Bros.png)"></div>
```

Note that I had mentioned `background-clip` and not `background-origin` in the above sentence. It is the `background-clip` that actually clips the background and not the `background-origin`. When only one box value is provided, both clip and origin are assumed to have the same value.

> **As per [W3C Spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background)**
>
> If one  value is present then it sets both ‘background-origin’ and ‘background-clip’ to that value. If two values are present, then the first sets ‘background-origin’ and the second ‘background-clip’.

---

> Now the image goes to the edge, the image should be padded, and the color should not be, possible with separate rules but not one line.<sup>[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420107/background-color-behind-div-padding#comment54629617_33420107)</sup>

If you mean to say that `background-image` is required (and must be restricted to content area only) whereas the color gets applied to padding area also as indicated in your question and comment [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420107/background-color-behind-div-padding), the code provided in question will not work as-is.

When you use the shorthand `background` property to assign a value to the `background-clip` (like in question), you are giving it only a single value and so the same setting would apply to both the color and the image. This means both image and color will be clipped either to padding-box or content-box as applicable.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background: grey center / contain no-repeat content-box;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/50/NES_Super_Mario_Bros.png)"></div>
```

---

You **can still achieve what you need** by using shorthand property but you have to use either of the following options:

**Method 1:** Assign  both the image and color in the same line like in the below snippet. The shorthand property works here because we are assigning clip values specifically for the color and the image.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/50/NES_Super_Mario_Bros.png) center / contain no-repeat content-box, grey center / contain no-repeat padding-box;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Method 2:** Assign separate values for the `background-origin` and `background-clip` properties like in below snippet (pointed out in [comment by Karsten Buckstegge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419754/single-line-background-style/33429237#comment54631044_33419754) also).

This works because of two reasons:

- Background colors don't have a size, they fill up the entire area within the scope of the clip. So, color becomes available under padding area also.
- Background image's size is set to `contain` and as per spec this means that the image must be scaled to fit the **background positioning area** which is nothing but the `background-origin` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115024/weird-gradient-border-effect/31120774#31120774). Since `background-origin` is only `content-box` and `background-repeat` is set to `no-repeat`, the image will not occupy the padding area.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background: grey center / contain no-repeat content-box padding-box;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/50/NES_Super_Mario_Bros.png)"></div>
```

Note that the image must be specified before the color because the one that is specified first becomes the top-most layer. If you add color before image then color will hide the image.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the shorthand.

If you just set one  value in the end (in this case 'content-box'), it will set background-origin AND background-clip to that value. Therefor you have to set your background-clip after that to have it correct. 
Final code then looks like this:

```
background: grey center / contain no-repeat content-box border-box;
```

See [W3C background spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background) on that.

Comment: Nice one pal. Sorry that I didn't note your comment (hidden so far down the chain) before adding the same solution in my answer. So, I added a link to your comment.

Comment: No worries. I just put it up here again as a TL;DR version.