# How to move background gradient independent from container width

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have a linear gradient: `2em red, 4em yellow`

```
.bar {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, red 0, red 2em, yellow 2em, yellow 6em);
    background-position-x: 0em;
}
```

If I move the gradient one `1em` to the right via `background-position-x: 1em;`

I expect that that my gradient will start with a `1em yellow` block and a `2em red` block.

Instead it grabs the previous last block at the end of the div which was red. So I get then `3em red, 4em yellow`, which breaks my rule.

Here is a demo:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXmOPB?editors=110

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeating gradients have cyclic repetition and so without an explicit `background-size` setting added you'd have to treat it as though tiles of `31em` are placed one next to the other. So when background's position in x-axis is set as `1em`, it kind of becomes like `-30em` to `1em` is one tile, `1em` to `32em` will be another tile and so on. This the reason why you see the last `1em` of the first tile (which is red) and the rest of the second tile (which `6em` * 5) as the background image within the container.

The reason for the background gradient image's size being taken as `31em` is discussed in the answer I had provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115024/weird-gradient-border-effect/31120774#31120774).

---

The solution to your problem is to explicitly set the `background-size` in X-axis as equal to your actual gradient size.

```css
.foo div.bar {
  width: 31em;
  height: 2em;
}
.foo2 div.bar {
  width: 33em;
  height: 2em;
}
.bar {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, red 0, red 2em, yellow 2em, yellow 6em);
  background-size: 6em 100%;
  background-position-x: 1em;
}

/* Just for demo */
div {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="foo2">
  <div class="bar">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Also, please note that `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` were initially proposed for CSS3 (and got rejected). It is [now approved for Level 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653685/is-background-position-x-background-position-y-a-standard-w3c-css-property) but to support the older browsers also it is better to use the shorthand property like given below. I just verified that some older Firefox versions do not support `background-position-x`.

```
background-position: 1em 0em;
```